# spring multipart resolver configuration issue using groovy config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy

I've  a spring controller for handling multipart requests.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file/fileStoreService")
class FileStoreService {

    @Autowired
    FileSystemStore fileSystemStore

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String saveOrUpdate(@RequestParam(value="data",required = false) String jsonData, @RequestParam(value="file",required =false) MultipartFile file) {


        println 'data '+jsonData
        println file

        Map data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, HashMap)
        String filestore = data.remove('filestore')

        fileSystemStore.saveOrUpdate(data, filestore, file)
        fileSystemStore.createFileChangelogs(data, filestore)

        return ''
    }


}
```

And I've configured the multiPartResolver bean in my appContext.groovy.( I am using groovy for configuration) as below

```
mvc.'annotation-driven'()
    multiPartResolver(CommonsMultipartResolver){
        maxUploadSize=500
    }
```

But when I try to submit a multipart request to the controller it still complains that multipartResolver is not configured as

> Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver
>   configured?

Am I missing anything here.I've not found any examples of how to configure multipartResolver with groovy config.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oops there's  a typo in bean id definition.

It should be **multipartResolver** instead of **multiPartResolver**

Solved the problem.